# extract string from html tag with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html file like this in a subdirectory `the_files`

```
<div class='log'>start</div>
<div class='ts'>2017-03-14 09:17:52.859 +0800&nbsp;</div><div class='log'>bla bla bla</div>
<div class='ts'>2017-03-14 09:17:55.619 +0800&nbsp;</div><div class='log'>aba aba aba</div>
...
...
```

I want to extract the string in each tag and print it like this on terminal

```
2017-03-14 09:17:52.859 +0800 , bla bla bla
2017-03-14 09:17:55.619 +0800 , aba aba aba
...
...
```

I want to ignore the first line of `<div class='log'>start</div>`.

My code so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = "the_files/"
def do_task_html():
    dir_path = os.listdir(path)
    for file in dir_path:
        if file.endswith(".html"):
            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path+file))
            item1 = [element.text for element in soup.find_all("div", "ts")]
            string1 = ''.join(item1)
            item2 = [element.text for element in soup.find_all("div", "log")]
            string2 = ''.join(item2)
            print string1 + "," + string2
```

This code produces result as follows

```
2017-03-14 09:17:52.859 +0800 2017-03-14 09:17:55.619 +0800 , start bla bla bla  aba aba aba ... ...
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch each div by class get its text and their `next_sibling` text.

```
for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="ts"):
    print ("%s, %s") % (div.get_text(strip=True), div.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True))
```

Outputs:

```
2017-03-14 09:17:52.859 +0800, bla bla bla
2017-03-14 09:17:55.619 +0800, aba aba aba
```

Comment: thank you for your fast response and great answer. It worked!